# Is it possible to use Jsp include tag as iframe source?

Tags: jsp, iframe, include

Is it possible to use something like this

```
<iframe frameborder="0" id="xxx" src="<jsp:include page="feed_cube_retreival?feed_id=<%=list.get(i) %>"></jsp:include>"></iframe>
```

Comment: Have you tried it ? did you get any errors ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" id="xxx" src="feed_cube_retreival?feed_id=<%=list.get(i) %>"></iframe>
```